# Existence of an open set which contains a compact subset

Tags: general-topology

In general metric space $X$, we know compactness implies boundedness and closedness(the other way around it's not always true).

If there exist a proper compact subset $E$ of $X$ and a point $x\in E^c$, we can easily form an open set $U$ s.t. $E\subsetneq U\subsetneq \bar{U}\subsetneq X$. (The construction of $U$ is similar to the step of finding a finite subcover in the proof of that compactness implies closedness.)

But if our space $X$ now is only locally compact and Hausdorff and $E\subsetneq  X$, $E$ being compact, can we still have the existence of such an $U$, i.e. can we still find an open set $U$ s.t. $E\subsetneq U\subsetneq \bar{U}\subsetneq X$?

---

**Edit:** I have proved the claim is true whenever $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff connected space. For details please refer to my post.

---

**Second edit:** As @Henno commented, a connected metric space need not be locally compact at all.(cf. [Michael's Answer in this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/21674/michael-greinecker)). The local compactness remains necessary as a separate assumption.

Comment: I assume you want $x\not\in \bar U$ also.  The proof of the amended proposition that there exists open $U$ with $E\subseteq U$  and $x\not\in \bar U$ uses $only$ that $X$ is Hausdorff and that $E$ is compact.

Comment: Yea, $x\notin \bar{U}$ should be true. By the way I have written out a rigorous proof as a post. If you are interested, you may take a look, though it seems a bit tedious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $X$ connected and LCH (locally compact Hausdorff ) we do have the strict inclusions you crave.

First we have $K \subseteq U \subseteq \overline{U} \subseteq V$ by the standard results for any $K$ compact and open $V$ around it, where I do assume $V \neq X$. (If you know $K$ has a compact neighbourhood $N$ inside $V$, then taking $U=\operatorname{int}(N)$ is enough for the first fact, which also shows we can assume $\overline{U}$ is also compact).

So the condition of connectedness then implies all these inclusions are strict or else we would have a non-trivial clopen subset of $X$ which cannot be ($K$ is compact and hence closed so cannot equal the open set $U$, etc.).

The only trivialities to avoid are $V=X$ and $K=\emptyset$, really. Use a modified argument if you need to cover these cases as well.

As a follow up to the comments: suppose $E$ is compact in an LCH space $X$, there is some $ f \in C_c(X)$ that is $1$ on $E$: this is trivial if $X= E$ and so $X$ is compact too as the constant function with value $1$ then works. So assume $E \neq X$ wlog.

Then let $\alpha X$ be the one-point conpactification of $X$ which is compact Hausdorff and so normal and we always have some point $\infty \in \alpha  X \setminus E$. ( take the conpactifying point if $X$ is not compact and any point not in $E$ otherwise) As $E$ is closed and $\alpha X$ is normal we have open neighbourhoods $U$ of $E$ and $V$ of $\infty$ that have disjoint closures. We can then define a Urysohn function $f$ that is $1$ on $E$ and $0$ on $\overline{V}$ and this function is as required (when we restrict it back to $X$ in the non-compact case of course); the support of $f$ is a subset of the compact $X \setminus V$.

Comment: Yea, I didn’t find out that we can use the condition of connectedness to derive strict inclusions until the very last step in my answer. With this idea things are getting easier. By the way, I think in the case that $K=\emptyset$, the inclusions may not remain valid. Suppose there is a topological space {x} with topology $\{\emptyset, \{ x\}\, \}$. Then this space is connected and LCH. But we can not even find an open proper subset $U$ in the space.

Comment: @SamWong Yes you want to avoid such trivialities. But why is the strictness so important to you? Applications never need it. Lots of zero-dimensional LCH spaces that are used in analysis (where the $U$ can be clopen and compact, often). You still get Urysohn functions etc.

Comment: Fair enough. In a proof in Folland’s book, he has used the Urusohn’s Lemma but the condition is merely that $X$ is LCH and $E$ is a compact subset in $X$(not even mention proper inclusion). He says that there exists a function $f\in C_c(X,[0,1])$ s.t. $f=1$ on $E$. But as for the Urysohn’s Lemma for LCH spaces in his book, an open set $V$ which separates $E$ and $X$ in the way that $E\subset V\subset X$ is needed. Also he uses the condition that $\partial V\neq \emptyset$. For this last condition we need $V\neq X$ since $\partial X=\emptyset$.

Comment: But even though $V \subsetneq X$, for disconnected LCH space $X$, $V$ is still likely to be both open and closed, which forces the boundary $\partial V=\emptyset$. I feel like his proof has so many flaws.

Comment: @SamWong $V$ cannot be open and closed, right? We know $X$ is connected…Ah, but not in Folland’s proof. I see. But $V \neq X$ is easily arranged: take $x \notin K$ and use $V=X\setminus \{x\}$ e.g.

Comment: Yea, I was talking about general LCH spaces which may not be connected. The condition of connectedness is not assumed in the Folland’s proof I mentioned above. Can you give me a counterexample for the following statement. Suppose $X$ is merely LCH and $E$ is compact in $X$. He says we can then have a function $f\in C_c(X,[0,1])$ s.t. $f=1$ on $E$ by Urysohn’s Lemma. I strongly feel like this claim is not true but I can’t come up with a counterexample. Have been stuck in this part for a whole day…

Comment: @SamWong yes this true and very easy to prove via the one point compactification of $X$.

Comment: … Jesus what I was doing… Do you have any reference that I can refer to for this stuff? Thanks.

Comment: @SamWong I added the argument to the body. No citations are needed as it’s all standard topology. It’s in any good text book in general topology that covers local compactness and the one-point compactification.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Amsmath's counterexample, I found that connectedness is a necessary condition to my claim.

Hence, we suppose that our space $X$ is locally compact Hausdorff **connected**, which means $X$ is locally compact, Hausdorff, and connected. Suppose $E\subsetneq X$, $E$ being compact, nonempty.

We claim that there exists an open set $U$ s.t. $E\subsetneq U\subsetneq \bar{U}\subsetneq X$.

**Proof:**

Since $E\subsetneq X$, there exists $y\in X \setminus E$.

Since $X$ is Hausdorff, we can find open sets $U, V$ s.t. $E\subset U$ and $y\in V$. (This is an elementary result from general topology, which can be found in any textbook on basic topology.)

> **Proposition** $4.30$ (*p. $131$, Real Anlysis, Folland*) : If $X$ is a locally compact Hausdorff space, $U\subset X$ is open, and $x\in U$, then there is a compact neighborhood $N$ of $x$ such that $N\subset U$.
>
> - *A detailed proof could be found in the refered book.*

By Proposition $4.30$, there exists a compact set $F$ s.t. $y\in F \subset V$. Compact subset in Hausdorff space is closed.

So we have already had two separated compact subsets which are separated by two disjoint open sets. We therefore use Urysohn's Lemma to derive a continuous function $f\in C(X,[0,1])$ s.t. $f=1$ on $E$ and $f=0$ on $F$.

For a topological space $Z$, $Z$ is connected iff all continous functions from $Z$ to $\{ 0,1\}$ are constant, where $\{ 0,1\}$ is the two-point space endowed with the discrete topology.

$X$ is connected and we have a non-constant continuous function $f$ from $X$ to $[0,1]$ and $f$ can attain values $0$ and $1$, so we conclude that $\{ 0,1\}\subsetneq f(X)$, i.e. $f$ can attain at least a number $q$ with $0<q<1.$

Let $0<r<q.$

Note that $(r,1]$ is open in $[0,1]$.

$\Longrightarrow f^{-1}(\,(r,1])$ properly contains $E$, being open in $X$, nonempty.

Note that $F\cap f^{-1}(\,(r,1])=\emptyset$ since $f=0$ on $F$.

Hence, if we denote $f^{-1}(\,(r,1])$ by $V$, then we have shown that $E\subsetneq V \subsetneq X.$

For each $x\in E,$ we note that $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$. Appealing to Prop. $4.30$ one more time, we can find a compact neighborhood $N_x$ of $x$ with $N_x \subset V$.

Then $\{N_x^o \}_{x\in E}$ forms an open cover of $E$, where $N_x^o$ means the interior of $N_x$. So there exists a finite subcover $\{N_{x_j}^o \}_{j=1}^n$. Let $U=\cup_{j=1}^n N_{x_j^o}$. Then $E\subset U$ and $\bar{U}=\cup_{j=1}^n N_{x_j},$ where the last equality is true in locally compact topological space. We can also infer that $\bar{U}$ is compact since it is a finite union of compact sets.

Lastly, we have shown that there exists an open set $U$, s.t. $E\subsetneq U\subsetneq \bar{U} \subsetneq V \subsetneq X$. The first proper inclusion holds because $E$ is closed and $U$ is open and $E\subset U$ and $E$ can not be both open and closed by the connectedness of $X$.(the only sets which are both open and closed in a connected space are the whole space or the empty set.)

$\tag*{$\blacksquare$}$

---

**Remark 1:** In the proof of Prop. $4.30$, Folland has used the condition that $\partial U$ is nonempty. However, in general disconnected locally compact Hausdorff space, $U$ might be both open and closed, which forces $\partial U$ to be empty. But a trivial modification can be made to his proof to make the proposition remains valid.

**Remark 2:** If without the connectedness condition of $X$, we may not construct our desired $U$ by using the continuous function $f$ from Urysohn's Lemma. What can we derive is a much weaker result. If $E\subsetneq X$, and a finite set of points $\{m_i \}_{i=1}^k$, where $m_i \in X\setminus E$ for all $i$. Then by the treatment above and Urysohn's Lemma, we can have a continuous function $g$ from $X$ to $[0,1]$ with $g=1$ on $E$ and $g=0$ on $\cup _i m_i$. It seems like we cannot even find a useful set-contain relation.

Answer (score 0):

Your claim is not even true for metric spaces. As a counterexample, consider the set $[0,1]\cup \{2\}$ in $\mathbb R$ and $E = [0,1]$.

Comment: Thanks for your counterexample. I have proved my claim for general locally compact Hausdorff *connected* space(abbr. LCHC space) and in particular, any connected metric space is a LCHC space. Even though for disconnected space, I have also derived a weak result. I will write these as an post explicitly.

Comment: I have written out my words as a rigorous proof as above. If you are interested, you may take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @SamWong A connected metric space need **not** be locally compact at all. The local compactness remains necessary as a separate assumption.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Yes, you are correct. I will edit this info into the problem.